# Show that U is open set in metric space $(R^2,d_1)$ if and only if U is open set in metric $(R^2,d_{\infty})$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that U is open set in metric space $(R^2,d_1)$ if and only if U is open set in metric $(R^2,d_{\infty})$

$d_p(x,y)=(\sum^n_1 |x_i-y_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$ in $R^n\\$

$d_{\infty}(x,y)=max^n_{i=1} |x_i-y_i|$ in $R^n$

is this metrics are right ..what next

Comment: Do you have any idea about  [Equivalent Metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics)  ??

Comment: i have little idea

Comment: do you think that this idea can help you in your proof ? Or you are need to follow a specific concept in your proof ?

Comment: i need solution for this one